# Do I need an Enumerator for this?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I want to do this:

```
<div class="menu">

  <%- render_menu do |title,path,children| %>

    <%= link_to title, path %>

    <div class="submenu">
      <%= render_menu(children) do |title,path,children| %>
        <%= link_to title, path %>
        <%= children %>
      <%- end %>
    </div>

  <% end %>

</div>
```

The method `render_menu` would look something like this:

```
def render_menu(children=nil)
  children = Paths.roots if children.nil?
  children.collect do |child|
    [ child.title, child.path, child.children ]
  end
end
```

I'm not sure what the `render_menu` needs to return to get the three params..
The `render_menu` will grab the default menu items if no argument is given..

Comment: As an aside: the code `<%= children %>` will render the result of `children.to_s` that probably is not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `yield` and replace `each` for `collect` inside `render_menu`:

```
def render_menu(children=nil)
  children = Paths.roots if children.nil?
  children.each do |child|
    yield([child.title, child.path, child.children])
  end
end
```

You should also modify your template to not display the value returned by `render_menu`:

```
<div class="submenu">
    <% render_menu(children) do |title,path,children| %>
        <%= link_to title, path %>
        <%= children %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```